# Passing information to another webpage using <form> tag in an if statement

Tags: php, html

I've been trying to pass the information to the next webpage only when all the fields that need to be filled are filled.However regardless if the fields are filled or not , the information is still passed to the next webpage.

This is the webpage that has the fields

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Book A Table</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Book A Table</h1>



<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $numErr=$dateErr = $timeErr = $personsErr="";
$name = $email = $num= $date = $time = $persons = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
     $nameErr = "Name is required";
   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
   }
   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
   } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
     if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
   }
   if (empty($_POST["num"])) {
     $numErr = "Number is required";
   } else {
     $num = test_input($_POST["num"]);
     if (!preg_match("([0-9])", $num)) {
      $numErr = "Enter numbers only"; 
    }
   }



   if (empty($_POST["date"])) {
     $dateErr = "Date is required";
   } else {
     $date = test_input($_POST["date"]);
   }



   if (empty($_POST["time"])) {
     $timeErr = "Time is required";
   } else {
     $time = test_input($_POST["time"]);
   }
   if (empty($_POST["persons"])) {
     $personsErr = "Number of persons is required";
   } else {
     $persons = test_input($_POST["persons"]);
   }
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>


//directs all the entered information below to DBInput.php
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
   Full Name<br> <input type="text" name="name">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   E-mail<br> <input type="text" name="email">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   Contact Number<br> <input type="text" name="num">
   <span class="error">*<?php echo $numErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   Reservation Date<br> <input type="date" name="date">
   <span class="error">*<?php echo $dateErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
Reservation Time<br>(Mon - Thur: 18:00 - 23:00 Fri - Sun: 12:00 - 00:00)<br> <input type="time" name="time">
<span class="error">*<?php echo $timeErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
Number of Persons<br> <input type="text" name="persons">
<span class="error">*<?php echo $personsErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
Comments<br><textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea><br><br>

   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>

<?php
if($name!=""&&$email!=""&&$num!=""&&$date!=""&&$time!=""&&$persons!=""){ ?>
//directs all the entered information below to DBInput.php
<form action="DBInput.php" method="POST"  />
<?php }  ?>




</body>
</html>
```

This is the website that receives the information from the fields and stores them in a database

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "Client";
$dbname= "webassigment";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

}
//stores the values entered in book.php in each value
$value1=$_POST['name'];
$value2=$_POST['email'];
$value3=$_POST['num'];
$value4=$_POST['date'];
$value5=$_POST['time'];
$value6=$_POST['persons'];
$value7=$_POST['comment'];

//puts the values in each respective database field
$sql = "INSERT INTO booking (Name,Email, ContactNumber,ReservationDate ,Reservationtime, NumberOfPeople,Comment)
VALUES ('$value1', '$value2', '$value3','$value4','$value5','$value6','$value7')"; 

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do some weird type of validation. I've seen "custom" form validations but like this one never.

You've complicated way too much the things.

Usually the validation is made by javascript or jQuery and for posting the variables only if all are filled you can put the ajax request into a conditional statement like this :

```
var name = $('#name').val();
var email = $('#email').val();
var num = $('#num').val()
var dqte = $('#date').val()
var time = $('#time').val()
var persons = $('#persons').val()
var comment = $('#comment').val()

if(name !== null && email !== null && ... put here all your conditions  ) {
   form_data.append('file', file_data);                           
   $.ajax({
        url: 'DBInput.php', // point to server-side PHP script 
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: {name: name, email: email, ... },                         
        type: 'post',
        success: function(php_script_response){
            alert(php_script_response); // display response from the PHP script, if any
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Cz147 did that helped ?